# Why script tags referencing "localhost:3000" fail

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am in the middle of a massive refactoring of my companies' web services and in doing so we are splitting out our static web files (HTML, CSS, JS) from our auth server and our API service.  Our migration plan requires us to keep the old web server for backwards compatibility, therefore in order to do local dev I need to setup all my script tags to reference "localhost:3000", however, when I do that the requests fail in the browser

I can go directly to "localhost:3000/scripts/core.js" just fine in the browser, but if I put the exact same URL into a  tag, all of a sudden the request fails in Chrome. Doesn't give me an error or anything, just says "failed"

Anyone know what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: There's nothing in the console at all?

Comment: Well it does tell me that the script isn't secure because of SSL but I thought I bypassed that by clicking the little "shield" in Chrome and clicking "Load unsafe scripts". Is that not correct?

Comment: Hard to say for certain, but I'd start there. Load the assets over SSL - if nothing else, you'll need that fixed in production anyways.

Comment: well when i deploy to another env or PROD my grunt tasks change the script reference to be the full domain, but when im local I just run an expressjs app, so I need to hit "localhost:3000". What is the proper way to do this if I need SSL?

Answer (score 0):

Because "localhost:3000/scripts/core.js" is a filepath name but "http://localhost:3000/scripts/core.js" is not. The first gives no transport mechanism but tries to attempt to open `file:///` while the second specifies HTTP.

So `<a href="http://localhost:3000/scripts/core.js">test</a>` Or https:// as the case may be.

As far as SSL goes, this may be a separate issue. Is your SSL certificate signed for your local server or at least self-signed and accepted by your browser? Enquiring minds need to know but this may need to be a separate question.

Comment: I looked at a number of other articles and SO questions and I tried to create a self-signed cert for localhost, but i do'nt  see any difference in the browser. Same issues

Comment: You have two separate questions and problems then and you need to open a different question about the SSL one. Probably on serverfault.com